# Pass a function as a parameter in JS and access the receiving function's variables

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I'm not sure this is possible in Javascript. I want to access a function's variable through a passed function, (or if a function is passed via an 'onend' call).

```
function Outer() {

  var fn;
  var foo = 'this is foo';

  this.bar = function(x) {
    fn();
  }

  this.setFunction = function(f) {
    fn = f;
  }
}

var o = new Outer();
o.setFunction(function() {
  alert(foo); //doesn't work
});

o.bar(); //want to alert 'this is foo'
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/jde585nm/

Comment: If not everything, most things are possible in JavaScript :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this

```
function Outer() {

  var fn;
  this.foo = 'this is foo';

  this.bar = function(x) {
    fn();
  }

  this.setFunction = function(f) {
    fn = f;
  }
}

var o = new Outer();
o.setFunction(function() {
  alert(o.foo);
});

o.bar(); //want to alert 'this is foo'
```

and tell us if is what you need.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

`fn` in your case is functionally a callback. Call the callback with the local `foo` variable as an argument:

```
function Outer() {

  var fn;
  var foo = 'this is foo';

  this.bar = function() {
    fn(foo);
  }

  this.setFunction = function(f) {
    fn = f;
  }
}

var o = new Outer();
o.setFunction(function(foo) {
  alert(foo);
});

o.bar();
```

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to share the accepted solution as both this and Alvaro's work well. In the end, my actual script used Alvaro's solution below.